# How to download heroku running file?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, quick.db

Is there any possibility to download running app file?
Im using quick.db for my discord bot database and I need that running json database file with user data before restarting. When I will deploy a new build, then the old json database file from github will load and I will lose all new data in that database.

Thx for anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically upload the json file to remote storage (S3, DropBox):  you can do this at restart (if you can intercept the event) or at regular times (this might not work for you, it depends how often the db is updated).

You can read about some possible options on [Heroku Files](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285)

The download option is not a good idea because you need to secure the download endpoint (I believe you don't want anybody be able to grab your data) and also because the Dyno restarts at least every 24hrs (if you don't deploy for a day the Dyno will restart without notice and giving the time to download your data).

Comment: Thx for help <3! I already figured out how to solve it, but Ill keep your way in mind.